# How to choose num_resamples in SALib for Delta Moment-Independent Measure delta.analyze?

Tags: python, optimization, statistics

I am trying to use delta.analyze for a sensitivity analysis based on latin hypercube sampling for the analysis of the impact of input parameters on a simulation.

SALib provides a function:

```
SALib.analyze.delta.analyze(problem, X, Y, num_resamples=10, 
conf_level=0.95, print_to_console=False, seed=None)
```

The outputs are delta and S1, which I can both use for determining how large the impact of each parameter is. I have not fully understood their difference, just that delta is the shift of the distribution and S1 the shift in variance.

Now I wonder how to set:

```
num_resamples
```

What does this parameter do? I couldn't follow the explanations in:

```
[1] Borgonovo, E. (2007). "A new uncertainty importance measure."
   Reliability Engineering & System Safety, 92(6):771-784,
   doi:10.1016/j.ress.2006.04.015.

[2] Plischke, E., E. Borgonovo, and C. L. Smith (2013). "Global
   sensitivity measures from given data." European Journal of
   Operational Research, 226(3):536-550, doi:10.1016/j.ejor.2012.11.047.
```

Can somebody please give a simpler, more practical explanation?

=================================================================

What I found so far:

Taking more samples did not change the _conf values.

The _conf values are in the range [0,0.05]

Changing the conf_level did not change the interval

If I take num_resamples very small, like 1, the _conf values are NaN

Answer (score 1):

After reading the papers in more detail, I think I came up with a solution.

SALib's parameter num_resamples is based on the bias-reducing **bootstrap** estimate. B bootstrap replicates (num_resamples) of the given outputs Y. In Bootstrapping, a replicate is obtained by drawing a sample of n realisations from the n available observations, with replacement.

Bootstrapping: A statistic of an original sample can be approximated by taking an average over large numbers of smaller samples of the same size (with replacement) from the single original sample. This statistic is computed for each resample and thus the approximation improves as the number of resamples increases. This works because the bootstrap quantity can be expressed as an expectation conditional on the sample. After a large number of iterations, the bootstrap statistics are compiled into a single bootstrap distribution. Thus, a bootstrap value and the corresponding confidence interval is obtained.

However, choosing the number of resamples depends on the problem. There are several studies on this topic. 
I just did what Stata recommends here: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/bootstrapped-samples-guidelines/

1. "Choose a large but tolerable number of replications. Obtain the bootstrap estimates.
2. Change the random-number seed. Obtain the bootstrap estimates again, using the same number of replications.
3. Do the results change meaningfully? If so, the first number you chose was too small. Try a larger number. If results are similar enough, you probably have a large enough number. To be sure, you should probably perform step 2 a few more times, but I seldom do."